# How to create usable slugs from tenant names in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slug

So currently I have a test in Rails that says the path I visit is the tenant organization name (a column in my database). The problem is that this organization name sometimes has spaces which I cannot use in my URL. What can I do?

```
test "an authenticated user can add default amount to their cart" do
    authenticated_user = create(:user)
ApplicationController.any_instance.stubs(:current_user).returns(authenticated_user)
tenant = create(:tenant)
tenant.projects << create(:project)

visit "/#{tenant.organization}"
within(".row") do
  click_link_or_button("Lend")
end
```

The problem is this line:

```
visit "/#{tenant.organization}"
```

Currently, tenant.organization =

> Lucy's Farm

which is not a valid :slug. What can I do?

Comment: use friendly_id gem. https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score -1):

ActiveSupport's [`parameterize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize) method does exactly what you want. It will return a slug-able version of the string you call it on. e.g.:

```
irb(main):005:0> "Lucy's Farm".parameterize
=> "lucy-s-farm"
```